# How can I search for a hyphenated term like "git-svn"?

Tags: support, search

How can I search for an exact match to a hyphenated term like "git-svn"?

I was specifically searching for questions pertaining to said package. I had already seen two hits via Google, but I wanted to zero in on Unix/Linux. Entering the package's name in quotes, the results included nothing on topic, and one off-topic answer included the string "git/svn". In other words, quoting the term doesn't give an exact match.

As an experiment, I tried "fortran-lapack" in quotes. Those two words are somewhat connected in usage though not as a package name (as far as I know). None of the hits were exact matches.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tag for [git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-svn), you can use this in your search by surrounding the tag with square-brackets, for example `unix` within the `[git-svn]` tag:

```
[git-svn] unix
```

This may help you narrow down the results.

Comment: more broadly though? Is there any other way to search with a dash?